# Why pre-fetching component data with Resolve adds the same data when navigation to the route again?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to pre-fetch data before navigating to the route. When I go to a different route and then come back to the `target route`, the data is appended to the `route.data`. Inially I have 3 items in an array. When I navigate to the route for the second time there are 6, the third time 9 and so on.

The code:

```
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.items$ = route.data.pluck('items');
  }

  // properties
  items$: Observable<Item[]>;
}


export class ItemsResolver implements Resolve<Item[]> {
  constructor(
    private itemsService: ItemsService,
    private router: Router) { }

  resolve(): Observable<Item[]> {
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<Item[]>) => {
      observer.next(this.itemsService.getItems());
      observer.complete();
    });
  }
}


<div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async;"></div>
```

Comment: can you show us the code of your `itemsService.getItems()` method and all the relevant code around it? maybe you're appending the results of every call in this service, so this would not be a problem of your Component or ItemsResolver but your service.

Comment: Thank you very much for narrowing my search. The problem was in `itemsService` indeed. With every `itemsService.getItems()` query the same items were being added to the same inner collection of items.

Comment: Alright, good stuff, glad you found the problem